# Is $f(x)=|x|^2$ a $C^1$ function?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

$\bigtriangledown f(x) = 2|x|$ is continuous, so based on $C^1$ function definition $f(x)$ is $C^1$ function.

Can someone help me to confirm this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x$ is a real scalar, correct?

Comment: @BrianBorchers $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry I thought you are dealing with $x\in{\bf{R}}^{n}$, my solution works for higher dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $$f(x)=|x|^2=x^2$$

It is a polynomial function, hence it is a $C^1$ function.

Remark:

The compute $\nabla f$ that you computed is nonnegative, which is not the case. The derivative should be $2x$.

Comment: Can you explain why $\triangledown f(x)=2x$. Based on chain rule, $\triangledown f(x)=2|x| \triangledown |x|$.

Comment: What do you think the derivative of $|x|$ is at $x=0$?  Is the chain rule really applicable?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}$, so $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(x)=2x_{i}$ is continuous for each $i=1,2,...,n$.